# Pydantic `1.10.8` add custom field for Decimal type

Tags: python, pymongo, pydantic

I'm trying to replace `float` type in `Pydantic` models to `Decimal`. The issue is that I'm using `pymongo` therefore I need to automatically convert `Decimal` to `bson.Decimal128`. I've already achieved the behaviour than I can pass `Decimal` when I'm creating a new instance by adding `DecimalCustom` field type:

```py
class DecimalCustom(Decimal):
    @classmethod
    def __get_validators__(cls: Type[DecimalCustom]) -> Iterator[Callable]:
        yield cls.validate

    @classmethod
    def validate(cls: Type[DecimalCustom], v: Any) -> Decimal128:
        if not type(v) == Decimal128:
            return Decimal128(v)
        else:
            return v

    @classmethod
    def __modify_schema__(cls: Type[DecimalCustom], field_schema: Any) -> None:
        field_schema.update(type=DecimalCustom)

    def __repr__(self):
        return f'DecimalCustom ({super().__repr__()})'
```

And then used it in my model:

```py
amount: DecimalCustom = DecimalCustom('0.00000'),
```

Passing Decimals:

```py
MyModel(amount=Decimal(str(1337.1092)))
```

But now, when I'm extracting record from the database, I'm still getting `Decimal128` type of field:

```py
record = my_model.find(_id=obj(request.params.id)).one()
logger.debug(type(record.amount)) # <class 'bson.decimal128.Decimal128'>
```

And I need to get `Decimal` again in the end